# Issue with long text tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-grid

I have an issue with long text tooltip, whenever I am scrolling down to tooltip with long text it getting blur and scorll is continuously moving and whole screen getting disturb and moving continuously.

Could anybody please help me for this issue.

```
$.fn.aToolTip = function (options) { 
    /** setup default settings */ 
    var defaults = { 
        // no need to change/override 
        closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn', 
        toolTipId: 'aToolTip', 
        // ok to override 
        fixed: false, 
        clickIt: false, 
        inSpeed: 200, 
        outSpeed: 100, 
        tipContent: '', 
        toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme', 
        xOffset: 5, 
        yOffset: 5
    }
}
```

Comment: paste some code

Comment: $.fn.aToolTip = function (options) {
        /**
      setup default settings
     */
        var defaults = {
            // no need to change/override
            closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
            toolTipId: 'aToolTip',
            // ok to override
            fixed: false,
            clickIt: false,
            inSpeed: 200,
            outSpeed: 100,
            tipContent: '',
            toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',
            xOffset: 5,
            yOffset: 5,

Comment: some of your jquery libraries are conflicting with it. Check your console error.

Comment: No jquery library is not conflicting I checked.

Comment: Why not reference https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/